# Tip Calculator Python Based on Service

Tags: python

My 2nd question is to create a tip calculator based on the service. If the service is amazing then compute a 20% tip, if its okay compute a 15% tip and if its horrible compute a 10% tip.

---

EDIT: From Raj's comment [on the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860427/python-hw-questions-phone-number) with his code:

Heres what I have done for the questions

```
rbill = float(input("What is the total bill?"))
print("What was the level of service?")
service = input("Please choose amazing, okay, or horrible:")
while service = amazing:
    tip=(bill*0.20)
    total=(bill+tip)

print("The bill was $",bill)
print("The service was",service)
print("The tip is",tip)
print("The grand total with the tip is $",total)
```

– Raj Mar 8 at 6:22

Comment: Do you think this is a free coding service or something? **It's not.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a homework completion service.

Comment: He just forgot to include the code he has already written into the post. You can find it in the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860427/python-hw-questions-phone-number. :-o

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't represent itself as a question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the while loop you have in your code:

```
while service = amazing:
```

You should replace it with an

```
if .. :

elif ..:

else:
```

statement, and when testing for equality of a string value, you need to set it in quotes.

```
if service == "amazing":
```

---

Code below is what you (Raj) had on the other post linked at the top. I tried to edit your question, but it got rejected.

---

**Code below is from Raj's comment [on his other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860427/python-hw-questions-phone-number):**

Heres what I have done for the questions

```
rbill = float(input("What is the total bill?"))
print("What was the level of service?")
service = input("Please choose amazing, okay, or horrible:")
while service = amazing:
    tip=(bill*0.20)
    total=(bill+tip)

print("The bill was $",bill)
print("The service was",service)
print("The tip is",tip)
print("The grand total with the tip is $",total)
```

– Raj Mar 8 at 6:22